# Copy link doesn't have highlight when using TAB key to put it in focus

Tags: bug, design, sharing, keyboard, tab-key

I noticed that in the "Share a link" dialogue, after you press  <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle the buttons, if the "Copy link" button is selected it doesn't have a highlight around it like the other buttons in the dialogue. (The screenshot was edited to collate all the highlights.)

[image: screenshot of share a link dialogue]

Using Windows 10, Firefox 101.0.1 (64-bit), rev 2022.6.17.42396

Comment: This question needs more explanation as to what you're *really* doing. I *assume* you're "selecting" these by using the Tab key to change focus after opening the share popup (which starts with the input text field focused). After opening the share dialog, you hit the Tab key, which selects "Copy link", then Tab again to get "CC BY-SA 4.0", then Tab again and again for the Facebook and Twitter icons. If so, yes, the styling is different. The "Copy link" has no visible change, while the others clearly indicate that they have the focus. IMO, this is a bug in the CSS within the primary.css file.

Comment: @Makyen thanks, I edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: I can reproduce both on Chrome and Firefox in Ubuntu. The button is selected in the expected order and pressing Enter activates it but there is no highlight.

Answer (score 2):

None of the buttons are highlighted for me:

> [image]

Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 101.0.1

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer, I hadn't said explicitly that the highlights are obtained on focus by clicking or cycling the buttons - my fault.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce this on Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11.

Here's a GIF showing the issue:

[image]

This can be quite confusing to users who <kbd>Tab</kbd> around the site. It's hard to know if you're actually focused on the <kbd>Copy link</kbd> button or not, until you guess and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> / the spacebar.